# XML-RPC call using sortbyAge, how to create an array of struck?

Tags: xml-rpc

http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/server.php?methodName=examples.sortByAge

I have to make a RPC-XML call using this method,how to make a struck containing this example array as shown in the picture? I would like to test a method myself.
[image]

```
<methodCall><methodName>examples.sortByAge</methodName>
<params>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

I tried to do sth like this

```
 <param>
            <value>
                <array>
                    <data>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member>
                                    <name>Adam</name>
                  <value><i4>23</i4></value>
                                    <value>
                                        <struct>
                                            <member>
                                                <name>Filip</name>
                                                <value><i4>18</i4></value>
                                            </member>
                                            <member>
                                                <name>Anna</name>
                                                <value><i4>18</i4></value>
                                            </member>
                                        </struct>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                                
                            </struct>
                      
                    </data>
                </array>
            </value>
        </param>
```

But it says

`Invalid request payload xmlrpc element ARRAY cannot be child of PARAMS`

In fact any format of this XML I tried is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap it in `<params>` tag, Try this

```
<params>
<param>
<value><array>
<data>
<value><struct>
<member><name>name</name>
<value><string>Dave</string></value>
</member>
<member><name>age</name>
<value><string>35</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
<value><struct>
<member><name>name</name>
<value><string>Edd</string></value>
</member>
<member><name>age</name>
<value><string>45</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</data>
</array></value>
</param>
</params>
```